# Problem converting function with promise from JS to TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to convert my NodeJS JavaScript code to a TypeScript NodeJS base which is then converted to JavaScript when NodeJS runs. Helps me to keep types clear and some other helpful stuff JavaScript is missing.

I have a function which I call to geocode an address which works in JavaScript fine but in typescript I get the error that its not a function.

```
import * as googleMapsClient from "@google/maps";

googleMapsClient.createClient({ key: "AIzaSyC0HCjjidjijijes1sbMLG5k"});
export function geocodeAddress( address) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        googleMapsClient.geocode({
            address
        }, (err, response) => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(response.json.results[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

the same code in which works in JavaScript looks like this

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'AIzaSyC0HC2Turfkrofrofkroes1sbMLG5k'
  });


function geocodeAddress(address){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: address
            }, function(err, response) {
                if (!err) {
                //console.log(response.json.results[0].geometry)

                resolve(response.json.results[0])
                            }
                                        })
                                    })}


module.exports = {
    geocodeAddress :geocodeAddress
}
```

in typeScript it complains about Promise

```
TypeError: googleMapsClient.geocode is not a function
    at Promise (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\helper\geocoding.js:27:26)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.geocodeAddress (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\helper\geocoding.js:26:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\app.js:107:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\app.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\app.js:3:12)
    at app.get (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\dist\app.js:105:40)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\nodeRoot\CRMLS-IMPORT\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: I hope thats not your real google key :/

Comment: Nope I replaced a bunch of random char so it’s useless

Comment: this statement sums up the madness with typescript "convert my Node JS javascript code to a TypeScript NodeJs base which is then converted to JS when node Js runs"

Comment: In your JS `const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'AIzaSyC0HC2Turfkrofrofkroes1sbMLG5k'
  });` assigns the return value of `createClient` to `googleMapsClient`. In your TS you do not assign the return value of `createClient` to anything. When you try to call `googleMapsClient.geocode` you are trying to call the non-existent `geocode()` function from the module, rather than calling that method from the client object returned by `createClient()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS you are assigning the return value of `createClient()` to the `googleMapsClient`:

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'AIzaSyC0HC2Turfkrofrofkroes1sbMLG5k'
  });
```

In TS you are assigning the module's exports to `googleMapsClient`:

```
import * as googleMapsClient from "@google/maps";
```

In the JS version you can call `googleMapsClient.geocode()` because the function exists in the client object returned from `createClient()`.

In the TS version you can't call `googleMapsClient.geocode()` because `googleMapsClient` is not a client object, it is the module.

Change your TS to this:

```
import * as googleMaps from "@google/maps";
const googleMapsClient = googleMaps.createClient({
    key: 'AIzaSyC0HC2Turfkrofrofkroes1sbMLG5k'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Romen i figured it out, below is the fix now it works as the JS code..

```
import * as MapsClient from "@google/maps";

const googleMapsClient = MapsClient.createClient({ key: "AIzaSyC0HC2Tuekjrekfjkfj1sbMLG5k"});
```